# How to receive Bing translation for Telegram Bot?

Tags: php, azure, translation, telegram-bot

I'm creating translate bot, and I've selected Microsoft Translator - Text Translation from Microsoft Azure Market Place. 
For now I just want to have some practice and selected free plan for 2m words.
I've created bot, registered it and made it possible receive and answer user's messages.
Then I've gone to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx to receive access token. And probably there my problems appeared.
Now my code is:

```
 <?php

//Set errors show
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

    //Set bot's token
    define('BOT_TOKEN', "my telegram bot token");
    define('API_URL', 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.BOT_TOKEN.'/');


    //Set bot's receiving information
    $update = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
    $update = json_decode($update, true);

    //Receive user's chatid and his message to bot
    $chat_id = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
    $message = $update["message"]["text"];


        function sendMessage($chat_id, $answer)

                {
                  file_get_contents(API_URL ."sendMessage?chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".urlencode($answer));
                }


    //Receive access token to translate
    class _auth {

        function getToken($grantType, $scopeUrl, $clientId, $clientSecret, $authUrl){

            $ch = curl_init();

            $params = array(
                'grant_type'     => $grantType,
                'scope'         => $scopeUrl,
                'client_id'     => $clientId,
                'client_secret' => $clientSecret

            );
            $params = http_build_query($params);

            curl_setopt_array($ch, array(

                CURLOPT_URL             => $authUrl,
                CURLOPT_POST        => true,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $params,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array(

                    "Content-type: text/xml",
                    "Authorization: Bearer ". $access_token,

                )   
            ));
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            $a_resp = json_decode($response);
            $access_token = $a_resp->access_token;


        }


    }

    if($message){
        $a              = new _auth();

        $clientId       = "my app's client Id";

        $clientSecret   = "My app's client secret";

        $authUrl        = "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13/";

        $scopeUrl       = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com";

        $grantType      = "client_credentials";

        sendTranslate($message);

        $answer = $message;

        sendMessage($chat_id, $answer);


    }

    function sendTranslate($message){

        $message = urlencode($message);
        file_get_contents('http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/Translate?Text='.$message.'&To=%27ru%27&From=%27en%27');

    }
```

The idea is simple, user just post a word in one language, and bot returns the translation.

But, for now it can't.
I think the problem somehow connected with access_token, but I'm not sure.
So, the question is: how to connect my bot with Microsoft translator. Then send user's message to translator, receive answer from translator and send it to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I understood!

Here is the code. With all comments to make it clear for everyone

```
 //Create class of basic params which required to connection
class _translate {

    private $_client_id;
    private $_client_secret; 
    private $grant_type = 'client_credentials';
    private $scope_url  = 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com';


public function __construct($clientID, $clientSecret) {

        $this->_client_id       = $clientID;
        $this->_client_secret   = $clientSecret;

}
    //Create function for curl 
    public function getResponse($url) {

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL                     => $url,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER              => array(

        'Authorization: Bearer '.$this->getToken(),
        'Content-Type: text/xml'

        ),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER          => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER          => false
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
    }

    //Function to receive access token for translation
    public function getToken($clientID, $clientSecret) {

    //Set user's id and ST 
    $clientID           = $this->_client_id;
    $clientSecret           = $this->_client_secret;


    $ch = curl_init();
        //Set params for request
        $params = array(
            'grant_type'        => $this->grant_type,
            'scope'             => $this->scope_url,
            'client_id'     => $clientID,
            'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        );
        $row = http_build_query($params, '', '&');

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL                     =>'https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13/',
            CURLOPT_POST                    => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS              => $row,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER          => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER          => false
    ));


    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


    $response_obj = json_decode($response);

    //Receive access token for further operations
    return $response_obj->access_token;
    }

    //Set function for translation
    public function getTranslation($fromLanguage, $toLanguage, $text) 
        {
            //Create answer to server with specified curl
            $response = $this->getResponse($this->getURL($fromLanguage, $toLanguage, $text));

            //To delete xml tegs
            return strip_tags($response);
        }

    //This function sets url which our bot will call
    public function getURL($fromLanguage, $toLanguage, $text) 
    {
        return 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text='.urlencode($text).'&to='.$toLanguage.'&from='.$fromLanguage;
    }
}


    //Default
    //Translate user's message
    if($message)
    {
        //connect to our app with it's id and 
        $translate = new _translate('id', 'secret');

        /* 
        *  Set translation language first - from, second - to.
        *  $message - user's message
        */

        $translation = $translate->getTranslation('en', 'ru', $message);

        //get translation of user's message and send it back to user
        $answer = $translation;

        sendMessage($chat_id, $answer);

    }
```